# Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES while trying to install pgagent on centos 7

Tags: postgresql, boost, centos7

cmake -D PG_CONFIG_PATH:FILEPATH=/usr/pgsql/bin/pg_config -D STATIC_BUILD:BOOL=off .

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at cmake/FindBoost.cmake:238 (cmake_policy):
  Policy "CMP0057" is not known to this version of CMake.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (FIND_PACKAGE)

CMake Error at cmake/FindBoost.cmake:1327 (string):
  string does not recognize sub-command APPEND
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (FIND_PACKAGE)

CMake Error at cmake/FindBoost.cmake:1459 (string):
  string does not recognize sub-command APPEND
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (FIND_PACKAGE)

CMake Error at cmake/FindBoost.cmake:954 (if):
  if given arguments:

```
"NOT" "(" "system" "IN_LIST" "_boost_processed_components" "OR" "system" "IN_LIST" "_boost_new_components" ")"
```

Unknown arguments specified
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/RAID/application_software/pgAgent-4.0.0-Source/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".